# my android studio doesnt download the library

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, encryption, qr-code

i have tried to implement the following library in my android studio project but it does not download the implementation.

```
implementation 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
```

from [this](https://github.com/androidmads/QRGenerator)
my gradle(project) file is

```
buildscript {

    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        maven {  url "https://jitpack.io"}
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my gradle setting file is:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {  url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Vehicle Rental"
include ':app'
```

i dont know what i am missing any help?

Comment: Can please explain to us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Whats the exact problem?